# javax.swing.text.View.createFragment strange behaviour in java7

Tags: java, xml, swing, java-7, jtextcomponent

I have encountered strange behaviour of aforementioned method.
There is a legacy component that is used to display xml file contents, it works in java6, however when I switch to 1.7_10 it fails as end offset is out of view's bounds.

I have researched this problem a bit and found following method javax.swing.text.ParagraphView.findEdgeSpan(View, int, int, int, int)

This is method's code:

```
/**
 * Binary search for the longest non-breakable fragment at the view edge.
 */
private float findEdgeSpan(View v, int axis, int fp, int p0, int p1) {
    int len = p1 - p0;
    if (len <= 1) {
        // further fragmentation is not possible
        return v.getMinimumSpan(axis);
    } else {
        int mid = p0 + len / 2;
        boolean startEdge = mid > fp;
        // initial view is breakable hence must support fragmentation
        View f = startEdge ?
            v.createFragment(fp, mid) : v.createFragment(mid, fp);
        boolean breakable = f.getBreakWeight(
                axis, 0, f.getMaximumSpan(axis)) > View.BadBreakWeight;
        if (breakable == startEdge) {
            p1 = mid;
        } else {
            p0 = mid;
        }
        return findEdgeSpan(f, axis, fp, p0, p1);
    }
}
```

It creates view's fragment then runs on this fragment but offset boundaries are taken from outer view. And it may happen that bondaries passed to `createFragment` are out of view `f` boundaries.

Could someone explain if it is proper behaviour?

In javadoc for `javax.swing.text.View.createFragment`:

```
Parameters:
    p0 the starting offset >= 0. This should be a value greater or equal to the element starting offset and less than the element ending offset.
    p1 the ending offset > p0. This should be a value less than or equal to the elements end offset and greater than the elements starting offset.
```

As I understand p1 should not be greater than view's endOffset, is not it?